# Nothing will launch in VirtualBox Kubuntu 15.04

Tags: windows-7, linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, kubuntu

I installed Kubuntu 15.04 in virtual box on a Windows 7 Pro 64 bit host. It installed fine and so did guest additions. However, when I boot up the machine, I am able to log in, but when trying to launch anything, it doesn't display. It shows up on the task bar at the bottom of the screen, but I can't see it. I have tried clicking on it. It worked until I installed the guest additions and switched virtual box to display two monitors. I have tried switching it back to only one monitor, but the issue persists.

Comment: It seems that your system detect 2 monitors and send the new windows to the second one. If the windows appear as button in the _task bar_  you can try to click on it  with _ right button_ of the mouse. It should appear the possibility to send/move the program to a new desktop and close to it the possibility __to send/move to another display__. You should see 2 displays, one is selected, chose the other one.